# Should I make my application a service or a console application?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services, webserver

I am planning to write a web server in c# that will run on my computer. I've heard that windows services are good for such tasks because they can start on startup and because they run in the background and don't interfere with your work. The only problem with this is that I would like to see the activity on my web server through a terminal. I don't think services can do this, but it's not a big problem because I'm sure there is a way to make the service run the server and create a separate console application to interface with the server service.

My question is, why bother? Can't I just have a console application run everything and also handle the terminal interface? The only reason I would consider using a service is if it offers some kind of performance boost. Does it?

Comment: When you say "web server" do you mean an actual web server like IIS? or a webservice which listens for incoming requests on a certain port?

Comment: @Carl I'm not sure what IIS is, but "web server" refers to a public server that is meant to serve people websites using http.

Comment: IIS is Microsoft's webserver that runs on Windows - https://www.iis.net/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows service - is not about performance boost. Your choice depends on what is the main goal of your service. If it's just an utility app and you plan to start and stop it manually perhaps console app will be good for you, else IMHO you should consider windows service that store logs and/or push events + console/wpf/winforms or any other appropriate kind of application for monitoring purposes.

Comment: Thanks, I think I'll use a windows service in case my computer blue screens while I'm gone and I still need the server to be online after it restarts, which, to my knowledge, is impossible with other types of apps. Any suggestions on how to communicate with a windows service? My go to would be windows messages, but services don't normally have those sort of permissions do they? I've heard atoms get the job done, but I'm not sure what the most efficient approach is.

Comment: Message queues is good approach, but not the only. You may consider websockets or wcf instead or anything else you like.